# Querying Uniswap pairs from a Contract using Hardhat

Tags: solidity, etherscan, uniswap, hardhat

I am trying to replicate this contract on Etherscan at address 0x5EF1009b9FCD4fec3094a5564047e190D72Bd511
I went to the Read Contract section and entered the three parameters for getPairsByIndexRange
as '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f' (Uniswap Factory address), 0 (start value), 100 (end value) and it successfully generated all the pairs. The code as follows:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

interface IUniswapV2Pair {
    function token0() external view returns (address);
    function token1() external view returns (address);
    function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
}

abstract contract UniswapV2Factory  {
    mapping(address => mapping(address => address)) public getPair;
    address[] public allPairs;
    function allPairsLength() external view virtual returns (uint);
}

// In order to quickly load up data from Uniswap-like market, this contract allows easy iteration with a single eth_call
contract FlashBotsUniswapQuery {
    function getReservesByPairs(IUniswapV2Pair[] calldata _pairs) external view returns (uint256[3][] memory) {
        uint256[3][] memory result = new uint256[3][](_pairs.length);
        for (uint i = 0; i < _pairs.length; i++) {
            (result[i][0], result[i][1], result[i][2]) = _pairs[i].getReserves();
        }
        return result;
    }

    function getPairsByIndexRange(UniswapV2Factory _uniswapFactory, uint256 _start, uint256 _stop) external view returns (address[3][] memory)  {
        uint256 _allPairsLength = _uniswapFactory.allPairsLength();
        if (_stop > _allPairsLength) {
            _stop = _allPairsLength;
        }
        require(_stop >= _start, "start cannot be higher than stop");
        uint256 _qty = _stop - _start;
        address[3][] memory result = new address[3][](_qty);
        for (uint i = 0; i < _qty; i++) {
            IUniswapV2Pair _uniswapPair = IUniswapV2Pair(_uniswapFactory.allPairs(_start + i));
            result[i][0] = _uniswapPair.token0();
            result[i][1] = _uniswapPair.token1();
            result[i][2] = address(_uniswapPair);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I then copy and paste the same code into my VSCode but I am not able to replicate the result:

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');

describe('FlashbotsUniSwapQuery', function () {
  it('Should return the pairs', async function () {
    const FlashBotsUniswapQuery = await ethers.getContractFactory(
      'FlashBotsUniswapQuery'
    );
    const flashBotsUniswapQuery = await FlashBotsUniswapQuery.deploy();
    await flashBotsUniswapQuery.deployed();
    const result = await flashBotsUniswapQuery.getPairsByIndexRange(
      '0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f', //Uniswap Factory address
      0,  //start value
      100 //stop value
    );
  });
});
```

when I run npx hardhat test I get the following error:

```
  Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account
      at FlashBotsUniswapQuery.getPairsByIndexRange (contracts/FlashBotsUniswapQuery.sol:33)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
      at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:66:3)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:518:9)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
      at HardhatNode.runCall (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:510:20)
      at EthModule._callAction (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:353:9)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:106:18)
```

I have been working to solve this puzzle for the past 2 days but still no solution...

Comment: The `0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f` contract does not exist in your local Hardhat network.

Comment: By the way, I've already written a Uniswap V2 flash swap implementation. It is well documented and thoroughly tested. [Check it out](https://github.com/hifi-finance/hifi/tree/%40hifi/flash-swap%401.3.1).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks Paul!